# How do I get fields in the discovery tab for the fields provided in logs

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, logback

First off I am not new to Kibana just the DevOps side and to index mapping.
Can someone help to how I can have fields for my index for things like log level and price?

Example log message provided to kibana:

> {"@timestamp":"2020-09-28T19:09:05.438Z","message":"Received Message: {\n    \"timestamp\": \"2020-09-28T20:00:00\",\n    \"type\": \"usd\",\n    \"price\": 10877.07,\n \"volume\":39.065\n}","logger_name":"project.me.consumers.PriceConsumer","thread_name":"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2","level":"INFO"}\n

My current fields:

[image: My Current Fields]

What it shows under the log as json

```
{
"_index": "logstash-2020.09.28",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "------------",
"_version": 1,
"_score": null,
"_source": {
"log": "{\"@timestamp\":\"2020-09-28T19:09:05.438Z\",\"message\":\"Received Message: {\\n    \\\"timestamp\\\": \\\"2020-09-28T20:00:00\\\",\\n    \\\"type\\\": \\\"usd\\\",\\n    \\\"price\\\": 10877.07,\\n \\\"volume\\\":39.065\\n}\",\"logger_name\":\"project.me.consumers.PriceConsumer\",\"thread_name\":\"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2\",\"level\":\"INFO\"}\n",
"stream": "stdout",
"docker": {
  "container_id": "------------------------------"
},
"kubernetes": {
  "container_name": "db-gateway",
  "namespace_name": "------------------------------",
  "pod_name": ------------------------------",
  "container_image": "------------------------------:1.0.0-b40",
  "container_image_id": "docker-pullable://------------------------------",
  "pod_id": "------------------------------",
  "labels": {
    "app": "db-gateway",
    "pod-template-hash": "------------------------------"
  },
  "host": "------------------------------",
  "master_url": "https://------------------------------:443/api",
  "namespace_id": "------------------------------"
},
"@timestamp": "2020-09-28T19:09:05.438928347+00:00",
"tag": "------------------------------"
},
"fields": {
"@timestamp": [
  "2020-09-28T19:09:05.438Z"
]
},
"highlight": {
"kubernetes.container_name": [
  "@kibana-highlighted-field@db@/kibana-highlighted-field@-gateway"
]
},
"sort": [
1601320145438
]
}
```

Using fluentD and logback and everything is on my kubernetes cluster.

Config I have tried on log field:

```
<filter log.**>
  @type parser
  format json # apache2, nginx, etc...
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
</filter>

<filter log.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  stream_identity_key container_id
  multiline_start_regexp /^-e:2:in `\/'/
  multiline_end_regexp /^-e:4:in/
</filter>

<filter _source.log.**>
  @type parser
  format json # apache2, nginx, etc...
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```

My fluentd config:

```
<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag kubernetes.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type "#{ENV['FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE'] || 'json'}"
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_minion
  path /var/log/salt/minion
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-salt.pos
  tag salt
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^(?<time>[^ ]* [^ ,]*)[^\[]*\[[^\]]*\]\[(?<severity>[^ \]]*) *\] (?<message>.*)$/
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_startupscript
  path /var/log/startupscript.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-startupscript.log.pos
  tag startupscript
  <parse>
    @type syslog
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_docker
  path /var/log/docker.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-docker.log.pos
  tag docker
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /^time="(?<time>[^)]*)" level=(?<severity>[^ ]*) msg="(?<message>[^"]*)"( err="(?<error>[^"]*)")?( statusCode=($<status_code>\d+))?/
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_etcd
  path /var/log/etcd.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-etcd.log.pos
  tag etcd
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kubelet
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kubelet.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-kubelet.log.pos
  tag kubelet
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kube_proxy
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kube-proxy.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-kube-proxy.log.pos
  tag kube-proxy
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kube_apiserver
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kube-apiserver.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-kube-apiserver.log.pos
  tag kube-apiserver
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kube_controller_manager
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kube-controller-manager.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-kube-controller-manager.log.pos
  tag kube-controller-manager
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kube_scheduler
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kube-scheduler.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-kube-scheduler.log.pos
  tag kube-scheduler
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_rescheduler
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/rescheduler.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-rescheduler.log.pos
  tag rescheduler
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_glbc
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/glbc.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-glbc.log.pos
  tag glbc
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_cluster_autoscaler
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/cluster-autoscaler.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-cluster-autoscaler.log.pos
  tag cluster-autoscaler
  <parse>
    @type kubernetes
  </parse>
</source>
# Example:
# 2017-02-09T00:15:57.992775796Z AUDIT: id="90c73c7c-97d6-4b65-9461-f94606ff825f" ip="104.132.1.72" method="GET" user="kubecfg" as="<self>" asgroups="<lookup>" namespace="default" uri="/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods"
# 2017-02-09T00:15:57.993528822Z AUDIT: id="90c73c7c-97d6-4b65-9461-f94606ff825f" response="200"
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_kube_apiserver_audit
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  path /var/log/kubernetes/kube-apiserver-audit.log
  pos_file /var/log/kube-apiserver-audit.log.pos
  tag kube-apiserver-audit
  <parse>
    @type multiline
    format_firstline /^\S+\s+AUDIT:/
    # Fields must be explicitly captured by name to be parsed into the record.
    # Fields may not always be present, and order may change, so this just looks
    # for a list of key="\"quoted\" value" pairs separated by spaces.
    # Unknown fields are ignored.
    # Note: We can't separate query/response lines as format1/format2 because
    #       they don't always come one after the other for a given query.
format1 /^(?<time>\S+) AUDIT:(?: (?:id="(?<id>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|ip="(?<ip>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|method="(?<method>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|user="(?<user>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|groups="(?<groups>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|as="(?<as>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|asgroups="(?<asgroups>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|namespace="(?<namespace>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|uri="(?<uri>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|response="(?<response>(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*)"|\w+="(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"))*/
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%L%Z
  </parse>
</source>
<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
  @id filter_kube_metadata
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the [mapping set up for that type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) is that the `log` field is treated as text (or maybe even keyword). Elasticsearch won’t try parsing submitted text fields into json object structures. That’s why the payload needs to be transformed earlier in the pipeline before putting it to elasticsearch.

You might use the fluentd json parse plugin for that. Please see [the docs about it here](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/json). There is also [some special article on docker logging and parsing the `log` field](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/docker-logging).

Comment: So it is seeing it as keyword. I've attempted a few permutations on my fluentd conf, which I have appended in my question.